# Mounting docker container directory to a shared directory

Tags: linux, docker, mount

I tried to mount a Docker container directory by running the following:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=rusnlk,domain=corpnet,uid=root,gid=root,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //rusnlk/shared /opt/mnt`
```

This gave the error:

> mount: bad address 'rusnlk'

When I changed `rusnlk` with the IP address, this error occurred

> mount: permission denied (are you root?)

Then I added the permission flags `--privileged` and `--cap-add CAP_SYS_ADMIN`. With `docker run` while starting the container, this error occurred:

> mount: mounting //rusnlk/shared on /opt/mnt failed: Invalid argument

Is there any solution for this situation? Is there any other missing detail in the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing cifs package the mounting command worked!

It was because the base image I used was an `Alpine image`. Unlike `Linux` Alpine doesn't give proper error that the package is missing rather gives a common error

> invalid argument

to install cifs packages use: `apk add cifs-utils`